# A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

/* Here is the code that is having an issue*/

```
%macro numstats(var = ,file=, format=);
  %let dsid=open(&file.,i);
  %if %LENGTH(&var.) > 8 AND %VARTYPE(&dsid.,%VARNUM(&dsid.,&var.))='N' %then %do;
     Proc SQL;
       SQL code
     quit;
  end;
%mend numstats;
```

I am having the following error when running this code: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required.

I have played with this code extensively to try different online solutions and cannot figure out why I am still receiving this issue. Please help!

- Side Note: The reason I had to add this `IF` statement is to try to find out whether the variable was a date variable. All my date variables are `Date9.` so if it is Numeric and has a length greater than 8, then I want to add date formatting that I would not add to regular numeric variables. If anyone can think of an easier way to do that, then i am open to that as well, but please help me figure out this error!

Comment: You have not defined your macros %VARTYPE and %VARNUM. What are they doing?

Comment: You a taking the length of the sting that has the name of the variable with the %LENGTH() function call. Not the defined length of the variable.

Comment: The maximum LENGTH for a numeric variable is 8.  What you seem to be saying is you want to test the length of the defined format that is attached to the variable.  So if DOB has DATE9. as its attached format then the length is probably 8 but the format length is 9.

Comment: @Tom I thought that I needed to use the %VARTYPE vs VARTYPE in the same way that I have to use %IF vs IF. This concept is new to me and something that I was previously unaware of. So, even if I am calling the macro variables (&file/&var), I can use simply VarType and VarNum?

Comment: @Tom Also, you are right on with wanting to test the format length. Do you know of a way to adjust the code to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call data step functions within macro code then you need to call them with the %SYSFUNC() macro function. Here is an example of a macro function that will do that for you.

```
%macro varinfo
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Retrieve attribute of a specified variable.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
(ds        /* Data set name */
,var       /* Variable name */
,info      /* information attribute to return - Default is NUM */
);
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Example values for INFO parameter:
 NUM = variable number
 LEN = length of variable
 FMT = format of variable
 INFMT = informat of variable
 LABEL = label of variable
 TYPE  = type of variable (N for numeric, C for character)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Usage Examples:

%if %varinfo(&data,NAME)
 %then %put input data set contains variable NAME;

%put Variable &column in &data has type %varinfo(&data,&column,type);
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Notes:

The macro call resolves to 0 when either the data set does not exist
or the variable is not in the specified data set. 
Invalid values for the INFO parameter generate a SAS ERROR message.
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
%local dsid rc varnum;
%let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&ds));
%if (&dsid) %then %do;
  %let varnum = %sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,&var));
  %if (&varnum) & %length(&info) %then
    %sysfunc(var&info(&dsid,&varnum))
  ;
  %else
    &varnum
  ;
  %let rc = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
%end;
%else 0;
%mend varinfo;
```

Using this your macro might become something like this:

```
%macro numstats(var = ,file=, format=);
   %if %varinfo(&file,&var,type)=N and
       DATE = %sysfunc(substrn(%varinfo(&file,&var,fmt),1,4))
   %then %do;
     * do something ;
   %end;
%mend numstats;
```